# Using both log and stack on a pandas bar plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have some data that comes from amazon that I'd like to work on. One of the plot I'd like to include is a distribution of ratings for each brand, I thought the best way of doing this would be a stacked bar plot.

However, some brands are much more reviewed than others, so I have to use the log scale or else the plot would be 3 peaks and the other brands would be impossible to decently see.

There are about 300'000 entires that look like this

```
reviewID  brand      overall
0         Logitech   5.0
1         Garmin     4.0
2         Logitech   4.0
3         Logitech   5.0
```

I've used this code

```
brandScore = swissDF.groupby(['brand', 'overall'])['brand']
brandScore = brandScore.count().unstack('overall')
brandScore.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, log=True, figsize=(8,6))
```

And this is the result

[image: bar plot]

Now, if you aren't familiar with the data this might look acceptable, but it really isn't. The 1.0 rating stacks look way too big compared to the others, because the logarithm isn't in "full effect" in that range but crunches the better scores.
Is there any way to represent the ratings distribution linearly on a logarithmic plot ?

By that I mean if 60% of the ratings are 5.0 then 60% of the bar should be pink, instead of what I have right now

Comment: Although we do not have your data, there is no indication that the plot does not faithfully reproduce the data. Representing "the ratings distribution linearly on a logarithmic plot" seems contradictory. What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Added to everything that says @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, what do you mean by: "because the logarithm isn't in "full effect""?

Comment: I mean that if the ratings have a distribution of 60% 5.0, 20% 4.0, 10% 3.0, 5% 2.0, 5.% 1.0 I'd like this distribution to be represented in the plot.

As it stand right now the 1.0 seems way too big in comparison, because it's placed at the beginning when the log function's scale is still pretty linear

The data I have is mostly 5.0's and 4.0's, which isn't faithfully represented in this graph

Comment: So, don't do a stacked bar plot. The problem is you have a LOT of brands,  with what is going to be quite long.

Comment: @Skum "if 60% of the ratings are 5.0 then 60% of the bar should be pink" Then the tick labels would be lying. You have to decide if you want logarithmic or linear scale, you can't have both at the same time.

Comment: @Goyo I disagree that you cannot have both, linear and log scale simultaneously (a counterexample is exactly what this question is about and can be found in my answer below). But I agree that in such a case the labels would be lying about the data.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Well as long as you accept labels lying everything is possible. However if I look at your answer as if you made six linear plots, then sized them in a logarithmic scale, it makes some sense. The linear scales are not shown but you have to take them in account to interpret the graph, which seems like too much cognitive load to me. I think that plotting review counts (logarithmic) and distribution of ratings( linear) separately would provide better insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have the total bar height living on a logarithmic scale, but the proportions of the categories within the bar being linear, one could recalculate the stacked data such that it appears linear on the logarithmic scale.

As a showcase example let's choose 6 datasets with very different totals (`[5,10,50,100,500,1000]`) such that on a linear scale the lower bars would be much to small. Let's divide it into pieces of in this case 30%, 50% and 20% (for simplicity all different data are divided by the same proportions).

We can then calculate for each datapoint which should later on appear on a stacked bar how large it would need to be, such that the ratio of 30%, 50% and 20% is preserved in the logarithmically scaled plot and finally plot those newly created data.

```
from __future__ import division 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([5,10,50,100,500,1000])

p = [0.3,0.5,0.2]
c = np.c_[p[0]*a,p[1]*a, p[2]*a]

d = np.zeros(c.shape)
for j, row in enumerate(c):
    g = np.zeros(len(row)+1)
    G = np.sum(row)
    g[1:] = np.cumsum(row)
    f = 10**(g/G*np.log10(G))
    f[0] = 0
    d[j, :] = np.diff( f )

collabels = ["{:3d}%".format(int(100*i)) for i in p]     
dfo = pd.DataFrame(c, columns=collabels)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=collabels)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

axes[0].set_title("linear stack bar")
dfo.plot.bar(stacked=True, log=False, ax=axes[0])
axes[0].set_xticklabels(a)

axes[1].set_title("log total barheight\nlinear stack distribution")
df2.plot.bar(stacked=True, log=True, ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_xticklabels(a)
axes[1].set_ylim([1, 1100])
plt.show()
```

[image]

A final remark: I think one should be careful with such a plot. It may be useful for inspection, but I wouldn't recommend showing such a plot to other people unless one can make absolutely sure they understand what is plotted and how to read it. Otherwise this may cause a lot of confusion, because the stacked categories' height does not match with the scale which is simply false. And showing false data can cause a lot of trouble!

Comment: Great answer! @Skun say that the data have a "distribution of 60% 5.0, 20% 4.0, 10% 3.0, 5% 2.0, 5.% 1.0". But in the chart it does not look like that. Are you sure about this? Is not it in reverse order?

Comment: @lbellomo  In this answer I have not used the real data (as I do not have it at my disposal). Instead, I've invented some data myself in order to show how to tackle the problem in general. I've chosen here to use 30%, 50% and 20% to make a most simple example case. One can adapt it to other values, and also the numbers provided by Skun is an example case, used to make his question clear (in his plot he shows the real data, which are in general also different for each vendor, so the plot does of course not match with the stated numbers).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the problem with the log scale you can not stack the bars in the plot. With this you can compare each bar with the same scale. But you will need a much longer figure (5 times more). Simply `stacked=False`. An example with sample data:

[image: poke_example]

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions without the data (providing sample data is better)

***option 1***
use `value_counts(normalize=True)`

```
brandScore = swissDF.groupby(['brand', 'overall'])['brand']
brandScore = brandScore.value_counts(normalize=True).unstack('overall')
brandScore.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(8,6))
```

***option 2***
divide by row sums

```
brandScore = swissDF.groupby(['brand', 'overall'])['brand']
brandScore = brandScore.count().unstack('overall')
brandScore.div(brandScore.sum(1), 0).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(8,6))
```

Comment: Alright, I've just added some sample data in the original post. I've tried both option, the first one doesn't really seem to work as intended, the output looks like this http://i.imgur.com/PtB2QA2.png 
The second one is pretty good, we do lose some information because every single line is the same length but it gives a good overview of the ratings. The output is like this http://i.imgur.com/PKwUASK.png

If I end up keeping this one I'll probably remove the brands with not enough ratings